# Multimedia content in xml

Tags: xml, web-services, spring, cxf, jax-rs

My thesis work includes transferring of multimedia content as a request for service. The Web Service part is developed with Jax-Rs specification Apache CXF. The application behind the service is developed in Spring Jdbc style with MySql as a back end. The payload can be transferred in XML or JSON or any other kind.

My questions :

1. Is there any other way of transferring multimedia content(image,audio,video) other than base-64 XML encoding?
2. If yes, does Apache CXF the specification for JAX -RS support it?
   Please shed your thoughts on performance and other issues. I am interested in hearing.
   This article [here] (http://www.xml.com/pub/a/98/07/binary/binary.html), talks about how to handle multi media content, but CXF supports XML. I don't know about others.
   Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please read the [faq] and [ask] for guidelines on how to post on SO.  Your question is much to broad and vague, and invites discussion rather than an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't this any other way is supported. But Base64 works perfectly fine, so you can stick with it.

Comment: After retrieving an image from the database field(MEDUIMBLOB), I stored the image in (byte[] content) in java. I have encoded the content using byte[] encode_content =Base64.encodeBase64(rs.getBytes("a_content"));

Comment: Is that all! Did I finish encoding! If iam wrong please guide me